# How should I fix this hole at the top of my sink?

Tags: sink

See the image below. I imagine this is where a built-in soap dispenser or water filter would go. Until recently, the metal piece next to it covered the hole. But rust got the best of it. I just want to cover the hole again, ideally as flush to the surface of the sink as possible.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to amazon.com and search for "sink hole cover", you will find something that's acceptable.

Comment: I never imagined that this would be such a common situation that a generic search like that would work!